# How to deploy an opsworks application by cloudformation?

Tags: deployment, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

In a cloudformation template, I create an opsworks stack, a layer, an instance and an application. This template sets up and configures the instance by a chef cookbook of recipes and scripts. How can I deploy the application automatically from the template without clicking manually on deploy inside the stack ? After the deploy the defined Deloy recipes from the cookbook are being executed:

```
"MyLayer": {
    "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
    "DependsOn" : "OpsWorksServiceRole",
    "Properties": {
     "AutoAssignElasticIps" : false,
     "AutoAssignPublicIps" : true,
     "CustomRecipes" : {
       "Setup"     : ["cassandra::setup","awscli::setup","settings::setup"],
       "Deploy": ["imports::deploy"]
    },
     "CustomSecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "SecurityGroupIds" },
     "EnableAutoHealing" : true,
     "InstallUpdatesOnBoot": false,
     "LifecycleEventConfiguration": {
       "ShutdownEventConfiguration": {
       "DelayUntilElbConnectionsDrained": false,
       "ExecutionTimeout": 120 }
     },
     "Name": "script-node",
     "Shortname" : "node",
     "StackId": { "Ref": "MyStack" },
     "Type": "custom",
     "UseEbsOptimizedInstances": true,
     "VolumeConfigurations": [ {
       "Iops": 10000,
       "MountPoint": "/dev/sda1",
       "NumberOfDisks": 1,
       "Size": 20,
       "VolumeType": "gp2"
     }]
  }
}
```

An application looks like this: [image]

Any idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CreateDeployment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeployment.html) API call generates a one-off event that executes the `Deploy` actions within your OpsWorks stack. I don't think any official CloudFormation resource maps to this directly, but here are some ideas on how to call it within the context of a CloudFormation template:

- Write a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that calls CreateDeployment (e.g., via the AWS SDK for Node.js) when created.
- Add an [`AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html) resource to your template that's configured to deploy your OpsWorks app as part of a Deploy Stage. See [Using AWS CodePipeline with AWS OpsWorks Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/other-services-cp.html) for documentation on this integration. (Though it's an extra service + layer of complexity, I think CodePipeline is a better layer of abstraction for modeling deployment actions in your application stack anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done within the recipes. So in your recipes you'll have a function to validate the app name and if it exists then proceed with the deployment.

For example your deploy recipe would look something like this:

```
 if validator(node[:app][:name]) == true
   do whatever
  end
```

and this validator function can reside in your chef library:

```
def validator(app_name)
  app = search("aws_opsworks_app", "name:#{app_name}").first
  if app[:deploy] == true
     Chef::Log.warn("PROCEEDING: Deploy initiated for #{app[:name]}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please provide me with a documentation ?  @Manish-joshi

Comment: In the above example I am using opsworks data bag and the required documentation can be found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-app.html @Cloudgls